# Huawei Freebuds 3 pairing with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, huawei

I have a problem with pairing Huawei's Freebuds 3 via bluetooth on Ubuntu 18.04. I have already updated bluez til 5.50. All I got when pairing is a loading circle and then message `Not set up`. Does anyone got a clue?

Part of syslog looks like that during pairing:

```
Apr 11 13:44:02 kj-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Apr 11 13:44:02 kj-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Apr 11 13:44:02 kj-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 8427.752680] debugfs: File 'le_min_key_size' in directory 'hci0' already present!
Apr 11 13:44:02 kj-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 8427.752689] debugfs: File 'le_max_key_size' in directory 'hci0' already present!
Apr 11 13:44:32 kj-XPS-15-7590 gnome-control-c[22033]: Setting up /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FC_94_35_C1_C4_A5 failed: Timeout was reached
Apr 11 13:44:34 kj-XPS-15-7590 gnome-control-c[22033]: Setting up /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FC_94_35_C1_C4_A5 failed: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.InProgress: In Progress
Apr 11 13:44:40 kj-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Apr 11 13:44:40 kj-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
```

Comment: Did you manage to used Freebuds with Ubuntu 18? I was able to pair the headphones but I was unable to use the microphone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Restart the bluetooth service from the console:

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Open the bluetooth controller and check its working:

```
bluetoothctl
show
```

This should provide you with a name, alias and some other parameters. If not, then the following won't work and you'll need to check the bluetooth service/device.

Run the following:

```
agent on
default-agent
power on
pairable on
```

These may already be configured like this, but it doesn't hurt to run them anyway.

Check if your device is already registered:

```
devices
```

If your device is listed:

```
remove [MAC_ADDRESS]
```

***Replace [MAC_ADDRESS] with your device's MAC Address

Put your device into pairing mode and then:

```
pair [MAC_ADDRESS]
connect [MAC_ADDRESS]
trust [MAC_ADDRESS]
```

If this works, then you can exit with:

```
exit
```

Comment: Did everything, however as always I receive that terrible: `[Free1m[agent] Confirm passkey 406043 (yes/no): y
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed
[CHG] Device FC:94:35:C1:C4:A5 Connected: no`

Comment: After device removal it may need to obtain it again by enabling scanning with command 'scan on'

Answer (score 3):

I have the same headphones, same problem and I found a way to fix that. The problem is in Bluetooth LE and using this manual I can successfully pair my FreeBuds 3 with my laptop. I hope it helps you too.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292189/pairing-bose-qc-35-over-bluetooth-on-fedora/293967#293967

Best Regards, Vitaly Sulimov.

Comment: It may be helpful to explain the instructions contained at that link, just in case it becomes unusable at some point.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However it still doesn't work for me. All i get is:
`org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed` when trying to pair them manually.

Comment: @KrisJed It's very strange. I'm getting a message which tells me that I should verify the pin on the paired device. But because it's headphones there is nothing to check and I just click Pair. Looks like you miss that PIN verify request for some reason.

Comment: Me too, I click `y` as a confirmation and then I got en error<br/>

`[bluetooth]# pair FC:94:35:C1:C4:A5
Attempting to pair with FC:94:35:C1:C4:A5
[CHG] Device FC:94:35:C1:C4:A5 Connected: yes
Request confirmation
[Free1m[agent] Confirm passkey 167517 (yes/no): y
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed
[CHG] Device FC:94:35:C1:C4:A5 Connected: no`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Working for me for Huawei FreeBuds4 and Ubuntu 21.04.

Answer (score 3):

In my case on Ubuntu 20.04, I used the following commands:

```
bluetoothctl
devices
remove [MAC_ADDRESS]

trust [MAC_ADDRESS]
pair [MAC_ADDRESS]
connect [MAC_ADDRESS]
```

...and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the logs in `/var/log` if there is anything useful in there?

More information would be helpful, as it can be anything from "*is bluetooth turned on*" till "*bluetooth driver broken*".

Comment: I've added logs to the main post. What I did was turning on bluetooth, trying to pair, when I got message `Not set up` I turned off bluetooth. Can you recognize what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After a long struggle I managed to connect them. I do not know exactly what solved the problem, but my workflow was:

1. I updated system with everything what Ubuntu told me to. There were a couple of updates during last weeks.
2. Manually removed headphones from bluetooth devices in console.
3. I couldn't then connect them in console so I tried in standard system's bluetooth manager and they connected, just like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and I've uploaded blueman and etc another things in this page and the links given. However, it worked with a very simple and different way. I was connecting to the earbuds when I took them from its case, now I tried to connect it from its case (You need to open the hatch of the case and push the button behind for 2 seconds.) Once its colour turns to white and blinks try to connect from blueman through `Set up a new device` and after few trials and lots of patience :) finally it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If the following error occurs, try to reset huawei FreeBuds by pressing and holding again
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed