# Cannot pair Huawei freebuds 3 with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, huawei

First off, I verified that my headphones are in pairing mode.

Trying to connect them via the Bluetooth GUI, the Settings gets stuck and is not responding. Therefore I decided using the **bluetoothctl** tool and followed the steps of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225896/huawei-freebuds-3-pairing-with-ubuntu-18-04) thread with no avail:

```
Attempting to pair with 04:8C:9A:EF:8C:93
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled
```

Maybe this log will help: using the `sudo systemctl status bluetooth` I get:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-02-11 10:36:47 EET; 23min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 4588 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 19036)
     Memory: 1.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─4588 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
    (....)
    bluetoothd[4588]: Pair device timed out for hci0
```

Comment: The logs say your device is timing out. Have the headphones worked before or on other devices?

Comment: Yes, I have tried them on my smartphone without any problems. I have also unconnected them from it while trying to pair it with my computer in order to avoid "double connection"-related problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with Ubuntu 20.10
I followed the instructions here to reset the earphones
https://forum.huawei.com/enterprise/en/huawei-freebuds-lite-right-bud-not-working/thread/632973-891
basically keeping the button pressed for 10s. and then re-pair them

now they work

Answer (score 0):

I have FreeBuds 3 earphones and they couldn't pair with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS either.

I reset the earphones (push pairing button for 10 seconds with phones in the case until color led starts to blink).

Then I removed the earphones from the registered bluetooth devices in Ubuntu with the

`bluetoothctl remove [MAC]`

command, where [MAC] is the earphone's MAC address. It can be checked beforehand with the

`bluetoothctl devices`

command. After these I switched off and on both my earphones and bluetooth in Ubuntu and paired them from the bluetooth settings GUI.